# I can't unlock bootloader of my moto g xt1033 android 4.4.4

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, stock-android, motorola-moto-g

Guys I've been stuck at this step for a while. My device as Motorola says is unlockable and I also have the unlock code but still it says in the command window that error occurred. I've installed android SDK and in it I've installed the platform-tools and all the other build tools.

Link  to screenshot:https://www.dropbox.com/s/wgqpq7jdki6sik5/Untitled.png

Comment: Have you checked that there are no typos in the unlock code? how did you obtain it?

Comment: Typos? What are typos? And i obtained it from Motorola's website

Comment: Did you type it or paste it? Typos are where you mis-type something. If the code is wrong, get on to Motorola and get a new one.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in Android KitKat 4.4.4 which causes this issue. A thread in [the motorola forum](https://forums.motorola.com/posts/35e4d3be5c) explains how to resolve the issue.

**Follow these instructions only if you have upgraded to 4.4.4! If you have 4.4.3 or 4.4.2 it is more likely that you misspelled your unlock key.**

- Download [the boot loader patch](https://forums.motorola.com/files/51c3cbf839/G_4.4.4.BL_Fix.zip) (this the link from the forum)
- extract the ZIP file & read instructions
- **your user data might be erased as part of this process**
- Then run following commands:

  `$ fastboot flash motoboot motoboot_41.15_testdrive.img`
  `$ fastboot reboot-bootloader`
  ... your device will reboot in fasboot mode

  `$ fastboot oem unlock [UNLOCK KEY]`
  ... wait for unlock confirmation ...
  ... you might see some error messages here, ignore them...

  `$ fastboot flash motoboot motoboot.img`
  `$ fastboot reboot`

Answer (score 0):

It's a current issue with the bootloader in the 4.4.4 OTA upgrade. There are two solutions: If you still can, You should unlock before you accept the 4.4.3 or 4.4.4 upgrade (but in your case, it's too late as you have already upgraded to 4.4.4) or you need to manually upgrade the bootloader on your device to get rid of this bug. There is a thread on the Motorola forums to join the seeding program for the updated bootloader.